# Pass value of selected value from drop down list using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have dropdown list, and want to pass the selected option's value in table. When a user selects an option from the list its value should be saved in the SQLite table using Rails 4.

When a user selects 'Visa', its integer value must be saved in the table.

I need to know what I should write in my view, controller and model, etc.

```
= select_tag "payment", options_for_select([ "VISA", "MasterCard", "Switch" ], "MasterCard")
```

Answer (score 0):

Options for `select` must be an array of arrays, like `[['a', 'value1'], ['b', 'value2']]`. The second value is set as the option value while the first is displayed in the dropdown.

You can use Ajax to send the selected value to a controller.

Haml code:

```
= select_tag :period, options_for_select([['All Time','all'], ['Today', 'today']], 'today')), id: "select-time"
```

Coffeescript code to send the selected value to a controller as Ajax:

```
#send
$('#select-time').on "change", (e) ->
  period_id = $(this).val()
  $.ajax
    url: "/dashboard/main_dashboard?period_id=" + period_id
```